# What's the difference between an "Embedded" and "Mobile" processors in Intel's terms?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7

I want to change the processor of my Acer 5830TG.

The search for compatible ones went down to `i7-3610QE / QM` or `i7-2860QM`.

The one is Ivy (newer) and the other one is Sandy.

But the real problem is that the `3610` can be either `QM` or `QE`. The first one says `Vertical segment: Mobile` (same as my current processor) and the other says `Vertical segment: Embedded`.

Does this mean that the QE one is to be soldered? Or what?

Thanks

Comment: You want the QM processor. Note that the system should be able to accept any [Socket G2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G2) processor, but it may not have been tested by the manufacturer for processors other than the ones you've specified.

Comment: Mobile implies batteries for the power source, so low-power consumption is a characteristic of mobile processors (as well as smaller size and lower weight).

Answer (score 0):

They have a different application - for your Acer you definitely want the QM version. Here is a detailed side by side list of differences - from performance, to memory speed to benchmarks - too many to list here:

[Intel 3610QM vs 3610QE](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i7-3610QM-vs-Intel-Core-i7-3610QE)

Embedded CPUs are designed for cell phones, TVs etc.

Comment: *"Embedded CPUs are designed for cell phones"* -- Err, no.  The cell phone is practically the definition of "mobile".